# How to properly prove a group is cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

How does one properly prove a group is cyclic? For example the group $\mathbb{Z}$. And how does one prove something is not cyclic, like $(\mathbb{Q}^{+},.)$?

Comment: Depends on how much you know about the group. Is it cyclic? Give me an element that generates the whole group. Is it not? Show that any element does not do that.

Comment: What does $\mathbb Q^{pos}$ stand for?

Comment: I assume it's the set of positive rationals under multiplication.

Comment: It is the set of rationals under multiplication.

Comment: Assume that $\mathbb Q^+$ is cyclic, generated by $\frac ab$, where $(a, b ) = 1$. Find a prime $p$ that does not divide either $a$ nor $b$ and show that $p \not \in \langle \frac ab \rangle$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A group $G$ is cyclic when $G = \langle a\rangle = \{a^n : n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ (written multiplicatively) for some $a\in G$.

Written additively, we have $\langle a \rangle = \{an: n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

So to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic you just note that
$$
\mathbb{Z} = \{1\cdot n : n\in \mathbb{Z}\}.
$$

To show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a cyclic group you could assume that it is cyclic and then derive a contradiction.

So say that $\frac{a}{b}$ (reduced fraction) is a generator for $\mathbb{Q}$. That is
$$
\mathbb{Q} = \langle \frac{a}{b} \rangle = \{\frac{a}{b}n: n\in \mathbb{Z}\}.
$$
Now $\frac{1}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}$ so $\frac{an}{b} = \frac{1}{b}$ for some $n$. This forces $a = 1$. Now just note that $\frac{1}{2b}\not\in\langle \frac{1}{b}\rangle$.

**EDIT**: I see now that I mistook your $\mathbb{Q}^+$ for the set group of rational numbers under addition. I will update my answer.

So let's consider the group of positive rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}^+$ under multiplication. Assume again that $\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic. Then, again, there is a $\frac{a}{b}$ (reduced) such that
$$
\mathbb{Q} = \langle \frac{a}{b} \rangle = \{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n : n\in \mathbb{Z}\}.
$$
Now $\frac{1}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}$ so there is an $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{b} = \frac{a^n}{b^n}\;\;\;\; \text{(still reduced)}.
$$
So
$$
b^{n-1} = a^{n}.
$$
This implies that $a = b = 1$ since $\frac{a}{b}$ is reduced (i.e. $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

(NOTE: This is just one way to do this. It isn't necessarily pretty, but you can probably now find a prettier way to do it.)